# Write a Regex to find a brackets which only contains the alphabets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

Consider the following string and I want to replace a brackets which contains alphabets with space:

```
str = (abc pqr xyz (tttt) 2018(2))
```

I am expecting the following output:

```
str_op =  abc pqr xyz tttt 2018(2)
```

How to write a regex for above example

Comment: yout outcome doesn't make sense. (tttt) does not contains alphabets WITH space - so it should not be replaced. if your outcome is correct, the question needs to be: **replace all brackets containing (alphacharactars or spaces)

Comment: if you want to replace brackets, containing (alphabets AND space) the outcome is the income, because its nothing matches for ((alphabets AND spaces) only). the first bracket is containing alphas, whitespace, brackets, digits. the second bracket only containing alphas and the last one only having digits. so please write a correct question. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
(\([^\D]*\))|\(|\)
```

You can use this and replace by `$1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/27

Comment: its also capturing the (2) in ruby, its not working in ruby

Comment: @DeeptiKakade you need to replace by `$1` .It will capture `(2)` but will replace it by `$1`

Comment: I don't want to replace a (2), please see my expected output

Comment: @DeeptiKakade when you replace by `$1` it will replaceback what you captured.And we have captured `(2)` to it will be back.See demo.Its working

Comment: so if you are able to check it, why arent you able to fix this? whatdidyoutry.com

Comment: and maybe first read my comment on your question. your outcome isnt clear compared to your question!

Comment: @DeeptiKakade use `gsub` and in `replacement` pass `$1` or `\1`.